# Google Drive API Uses

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating one application when users can use his/her drive account to save documents. Can i use Drive API so the users save documents in drive? The users will use my app to upload pdf documents in his/her folder.

Comment: I am making this question because Google Drive Policy states "Backup of user/app content from developer’s app to Drive."  But users will save a proccessed document, is not intended as backup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the [Google Drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) to create, update and delete files on a users google drive account.

You Will need to use Oauth2 to have the user authenticate your application granting it access to their google drive account.

You should be aware that the Google drive api has a number of sensitive and restricted scopes which will make the [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) process a little more complicated than it would be otherwise.

[What you need to know about Google verification in 2021.](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)